# React: Removing first item in useState array after event (or timer)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I have a function that populates a useState array of objects: cars that appear on the left of the screen and animate across till off screen. After the car is off the screen I want them to be removed from the state array, so I can have an endless loop of random cars (at random speeds). The objects are labeled by 0-indexed keys.

At the moment I am trying a 9 second timer to delete cars, but this is just emptying the whole array after 9 seconds.
Thank you so much for reading/ helping!

```
const getRandomNumber = (min: number, max: number) => {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
};

const getRandomNumberToString = (min: number, max: number) => {
  const result = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  return result.toString();
};

const CarLeft = styled.div`
  animation-duration: ${getRandomNumberToString(2, 9)}s;
`;

const carListDay = [car_1, car_2, car_3, car_4, car_5, car_6];

function Traffic() {
  const [carsOnTheLeft, setCarsOnTheLeft] = useState<any>([]);
  const timeout = useRef<any>();

  useEffect(() => {
    timeout.current = setTimeout(() => {
      if (carsOnTheLeft.length < 30)
        setCarsOnTheLeft([
          ...carsOnTheLeft,
          <CarLeft key={carsOnTheLeft.length} className="car__left">
            <img
              src={carListDay[Math.floor(Math.random() * carListDay.length)]}
              alt=""
            />
          </CarLeft>,
        ]);
      else clearTimeout(timeout.current);
    }, getRandomNumber(500, 5000));
    console.log(carsOnTheLeft);

    setTimeout(() => {
      const name = "0";
      setCarsOnTheLeft(carsOnTheLeft.filter((item: any) => item.name !== name));
    }, 9000);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout.current);
    };
  }, [carsOnTheLeft]);

  return <div className="traffic__container">{carsOnTheLeft}</div>;
}

export default Traffic;
```

Comment: UPDATE! I have resolved the issue of cars moving the same speed by simply placing the "getRandomNumberToString" function into the useEffect. Easy Peasy, still looking for a clean way to remove the items after they have animated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one, to my knowledge React doesn't recommend modifying a state inside your useEffect hook when you also have it in your dependency array, this creates a circular dependency and an endless re-rendering. I think I know what you want to do, I just don't know if this is the best way to achieve it.

Maybe using setInterval might be a better idea since you want to repeat this indefinitely, and also removing the state from the dependency array, then inside the interval you start popping the first item in the list and pushing it to the last position. Something like this:

```js
useEffect(()=>{
 timeout.current = setInterval(()=>{
 // And in here add the logic for popping and pushing the cars into
// the state, alognside the logic for calculting the transition time
}, 9000)

  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timeout.current);
  };
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and it works perfectly! Instead of a timer, I used React's `onAnimationEnd()` function to trigger a handler to execute this function.

```
const handleRemoveItem = (e) => {
      setCarsOnTheLeft((carsOnTheLeft) =>
        carsOnTheLeft.filter((key, i) => i !== 0)
      );
    };
```

A declarative way to change the state array without directly mutating it.